# Using auto-generated data-methods in data-classes that implement an interface

Tags: kotlin, interface, data-class

In my very simple example, I have an interface 'Employee' which is implemented by 'Teacher' and 'Secretary'. Those two are data-classes. In order to see how the '==' operator works in kotlin vs java I have also overwritten the equals method. During my first tests I wanted to do the following:

```
val employee: Employee = Teacher(...);
assertTrue(employee == employee.copy())
```

This obviously does not work because even though 'Teacher' is a data-class, the interface does not know about the copy method. I read in the wiki that

> Providing explicit implementations for the componentN() and copy() functions is not allowed.

and am wondering if my only option is to write my own "clone" implementation? Or is it possible to somehow access the auto-generated copy method?

Comment: You can do a cast: _(employee as Teacher).copy()_

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, now that you mentioned it hehe..

Comment: Note that casting will crash at runtime if the object you have is not of type `Teacher` but is another subtype of `Employee`. If you really want to have a generic `copy` method on the interface that works for any subtype, you might need to create your own method for this